# How to exclude test assemblies from VS code coverage?

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage

So, I generate the code coverage report by running `dotnet test --no-build -l trx --collect "Code coverage"`. Unfortunately, it also computes the code coverage for the test assemblies. How do I tell it not to collect for test assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2019 and here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019

For some reason Microsoft thinks that scanning the test assemblies is a good default. Too bad for us. At the end I went up with the custom runsettings file that excludes the test assemblies manually and includes only those having our company name.

Comment: I have to say that I hate using .runsettings files. It would be better if there was a dotnet test option for that